# A variable with an assigned integer value moves down the line in shell

Tags: python, variables, text, printing

Can somebody please show me which part of the code makes the an int variable move down without being asked to do so.

```
    def option():
        file = open('firesideResults.txt')
        print ("\t\tPlayer Nickname\t\tMatches Palyed\t\tMatches Won\t\tMatches Lost\t\tPoints")
        for line in file:
                if line.split(',')[2] > "0":
                        player_name = line.split (',')[0]
                        matches_plyd = line.split (',')[1]
                        matches_won = line.split (',')[2]
                        matches_lost = line.split (',')[3]
                        points = int(matches_won)*3    
                        print("\n",player_name,"\t\t\t",matches_plyd,"\t\t\t",matches_won,"\t\t",matches_lost,"\t\t",points,)
                        continue
        file.close()
```

I expect the results to be laid out in the format

```
  Roy     17    10    7    30
```

however the output is:

```
  Roy    17    10    7
      30
```

I want to know how to make the 'points' variable next to the other variables in the line. Thank you.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that that many characters and tabs simply don't fit?

Comment: Your given output would be 82 characters wide, with PS/cmd tab stops. The standard terminal width is 82 characters.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I've reduced the tabs and characters to a minimum, but it still continues to happen.